# Python scripting for Bitbucket server API access

Tags: python, django, git, bitbucket-server, stashy

Anyone know how to access branch related operations pull,push,clone and also take backup of branch,repository as zip or tar file etc of Atlassian Bitbucket server 4.14 installed on local machine using python script I tried bitbucket-api module of python but it supports only Cloud REST API of Bitbucket...?

Answer (score 0):

Atlassian Bitbucket Server is former Atlassian Stash. [Stashy](https://github.com/RisingOak/stashy) is what you are looking for.

Comment: Stashy is old, it didn't support the new APIs.